# fadein the background but not the foreground

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to get a background image to fade in.

I have a `<div>` where the background image is set dynamically:

```
<div id="hero" ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(' + hero + ')'}">
    <h1>{{property.name}}</h1><br>
    <h2>{{property.location}}</h2>
</div>
```

and the controller:

```
$scope.hero = "path/to/image.jpg";
```

The css is:

```
#hero {
    height:350px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    padding:30px;
}

#hero h1 {
    color:#EFEFEF;
    font-size:30px;
    background-color: #232323;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px 5px;
    margin-bottom:3px;
}

#hero h2 {
    color:#EFEFEF;
    font-size:15px;
    background-color: #232323;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:3px;
}
```

I also have some css for the fadein:

```
.fadein.ng-hide-remove {
    animation: 0.8s appear;
    display: block!important;
}

.fadein.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
    opacity:1;
}
```

but I'm not sure how to piece it together so that only the background fades in and not the foreground i.e. the `h1` and `h2`

Comment: btw, you should tag it html and css. It's not really related to AngularJS.

Comment: It is Angular as I want to know how to apply the fade in to the ng-class

Comment: Sure you are using angular and are using angular ways to apply CSS. Though the issue itself comes down to pure HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If you set opacity to an element, it will take effect on all children.
The only way to prevent it taking effect on your heading is to not let it be a descendant of element with an opacity.
This is one way you could try to get around it.

```css
#hero #background {
  background: #000;
  height: 150px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
#hero h1, #hero h2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -80px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="hero">
    <div id="background">
      
    </div>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <h2>Subtitle</h2>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```